# Android 13 Photo Picker gives FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, uri, filenotfoundexception, photo-picker

I used a photo picker to retrieve photos and I follow https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker. We have seen a few devices below crash in Android 11 and above devices.

Non-fatal Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:156)

```
// Fragment  to get a photo uri.

val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { uri ->

    passToAdapter(uri)
}

Button(
    choosePhoto = {
        //On button press, launch the photo picker
        launcher.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(
            //Here we request only photos. Change this to .ImageAndVideo if you want videos too.
            //Or use .VideoOnly if you only want videos.
            mediaType = ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly
        ))
    }
)

   
Adapter:

// get application context .

val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) // crash at here.
```

Please note: I access this uri in different fragments/activities so if I use application class, I believe this should solve my problem.

I suspect the issue is because of the missing below lines

val flag = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
context.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, flag)

Comment: Are you saving that Uri to a database? Or accessing it immediately after you receive it?

Comment: Accessing after a few secs/mins but again, I have android 13, and it works fine without adding read uri permission but not sure why its giving error to other devices ?

Comment: What matters is accessing it from the exact activity instance that received that Uri.

Comment: will this work : application.contentResolver. takePersistableUriPermission(uri,  Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

Comment: You didn't answer the question, so how can we tell? You haven't included any code either.

Comment: Show your code. Your post does not makes sense without. We do not know what you do.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the code for your reference. I can't use a single activity context due to accessing the URI in many other places.

Comment: any clue for this crash? it only happens to a few devices in the prod.